# Taking only one item randomly from an angular js list

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a list of items, and looping an html code like this. (Pasted html snippet is not complete since its lengthy)

```
<div class="row"   ng-repeat="recentuseraddress in timeline"  >
    <div class="address col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-left"  >
        <p><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>property/index/{{recentuseraddress.home_id}}">
                <img ng-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/maps/{{recentuseraddress.propertyimg}}" height="50" width="50">
            </a>
        <p>{{recentuseraddress.updated_time}}</p><br>{{recentuseraddress.recent_connect_address}} <span>{{recentuseraddress.recent_connect_postcode}}</span></p>
    </div>
    ......
```

You can see the image tag in the html, basically it prints all the images in my list.

And now in a different place of same page, I need to **get only one image** from the same angular js {{recentuseraddress.propertyimg}} **randomly** .

Is there any direct angular js approach to extract an item from list randomly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use:**

```
$scope.randomImage= $scope.recentuseraddress.propertyimg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.recentuseraddress.propertyimg.length)];
```

And in view: **{{randomImage}}**

Comment: Thank you very much. Just saw a possibility, say list was empty and nothing to select randomly, in that case is there a way to address that in view

Comment: I am on mobile. So the answer won't be detailed. You can just check the list for empty condition and assign a scope variable with some statement and show that in view with the help of handlebars.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps

Comment: U have to tick the answer correct. If the answer helped you buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick your random element from the timeline in your controller.
I simulated your situation based on your code snippet and wrote this example.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('mainController',function($scope){
  var timeline = [
    {home_id:1,propertyimg:'img1.jpg'},
    {home_id:2,propertyimg:'img2.jpg'},
    {home_id:3,propertyimg:'img3.jpg'}
  ];
  $scope.timeline=timeline;
  $scope.randomRecentUserAddress = timeline[Math.floor(Math.random() * timeline.length)];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>Timeline</h1>
  <pre>
    {{timeline}}
  </pre>
  <h1>Random</h1>
  <pre>
    {{randomRecentUserAddress}}
  </pre>
  <img ng-src="{{randomRecentUserAddress.propertyimg}}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is also helpfull